# Intentando mostrar imagen con setAttribute()

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando mostrar la QRcode como la imagen desde JS y no me muestra la imagen como tal. Si pongo url directamente, me funciona perfectamente, pero desde el script no.

Esto es de .js

```
let string = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&amp;cht=qr&amp;chl=https://www.excelsior.com.mx/expresiones/candaya-presenta-sus-novedades-editoriales-para-el-primer-semestre-de-2022/1490716'
     
document.getElementById('news_image2').setAttribute('src', string)
```

y el html:

```
<img scr="" className='noticias_qr' id='news_image2'/>
```

Tambien he probado con el .src pero tampoco va:

```
document.getElementById('news_image2').src = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&amp;cht=qr&amp;chl=https://www.excelsior.com.mx/expresiones/candaya-presenta-sus-novedades-editoriales-para-el-primer-semestre-de-2022/1490716'
```

Gracias

Comment: El string que tienes no conduce a ninguna imagen. Prueba algo como https://picsum.photos/200 y verás que con el primer intento funciona.

Comment: Lo que intento hacer es generar el qrcode con el link que necesito y pasar este qr a la imagen

Comment: En ese caso deberías enfocar tu pregunta en cuanto al generador de qr que estás usando, no a javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el enlace está mal escrito. Tienes que eliminar los `&amp;` y sustituirlos por `&`, con eso tu código funciona perfectamente. Te dejo el ejemplo. Un saludo.

```js
let string = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl=https://www.excelsior.com.mx/expresiones/candaya-presenta-sus-novedades-editoriales-para-el-primer-semestre-de-2022/1490716';
     
document.getElementById('news_image2').setAttribute('src', string);
```

```html
<img scr="" className='noticias_qr' id='news_image2'/>
```